# perfecto mobile review

Tags: ios, testing, mobile

Can anyone let me know is perfecto mobile the right option for testing compared to a physical device, what are the effects of this on a native application and hybrid, does perfecto uses a emulator in the backend somewhere since its on a cloud it can only offer that.

Please help.

Thanks 
deepesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to to be fair, I work for Perfecto :-)

1. Perfecto uses real devices, not emulators. so no need to compare, those are real devices
2. there is no impact on the devices. or to be fair, there is minimal impact on the device (no client), with over 4000 devices implemented and hundreds of customers (including device OEM, carriers and many Tier-1 enterprises), we never got complain that the test is somehow not represent real device
3. the cloud simply help you reduce the logistics involve in owning the devices.